# how to put pagination and row limit to display in the table

Tags: javascript, php

Following is my code and I want to display data from `phpmyadmin` but I am not able to limit my data using a dropdown and I am not able put a pagination under the table.

```
<center>
<!--<div style="overflow-y:auto; height: 400px;">-->
<div id="parent">
<center><div style=" border:white;background-color: white;height: 6.5px; width: 94%;  position: absolute; margin-top:-5px;"></div></center>

<table align="center" border="2" id="fixTable" class="table w3-hoverable" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="w3-grey">
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>PERIOD COVERED</th>
            <th>VOUCHER NO</th>
            <th>MONTHLY HONORARIUM</th>
            <th>WITHOUT PAY</th>
            <th>NET PAY</th>
            <th>ACTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) 
{
 ?>
 <tbody>
 <tr id="row<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
  <td hidden id="no_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['emp_no'];?></td>
  <td style="width: 50%;" hidden id="name_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['emp_name'];?></td> 
  <td style="text-align: center;" id="date_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['date_n'];?></td> //data from database
  <td style="text-align: right;" id="period_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['period_cov'];?></td>//data from database
  <td style="text-align: right;" id="voucher_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['voucher_no'];?></td>//data from database
  <td style="text-align: right;" id="monthly_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['monthly_hon'];?></td>//data from database
  <td style="text-align: right;" id="without_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['without_pay'];?></td>//data from database
  <td style="text-align: right;" id="net_val<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo number_format($row['net_pay'],2)?></td>//data from database
  <td style="width: 200px;" align="center">

<?php 
} ?>
</table>
```

Comment: do you know the datatable js? just add the datatable js and rest of it will do it for you.

Comment: thank you dhaval-purohit. i already tried that code but it wont work. im still searching for some answer in related systems

Comment: i think it will work fine but if you go with your custom solution than you need to understand how you will make pagination and row limit in your table.